# how to prove this inequality $(ab+bc+ac)^2 ≥ 3abc(a+b+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that if $a,b,c$ are non-negative real numbers, then
>   $(ab + bc + ca)^2 \geq 3abc(a+b+c)$.

I tried to compute from $(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: isn't the bottom proof correct?

Comment: @d.v It's correct, but it's essentially the same as mine.

Comment: yes,you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a,b,c$ can be any real numbers.

Let $x=ab$, $y=bc$, $z=ca$. Then your inequality is $$(x+y+z)^2\ge 3(xy+yz+zx),$$

which is true, because $$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)$$

and the inequality is equivalent to $$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy+yz+zx,$$

which is true, because, as you said, it's equivalent to $$\frac{1}{2}\left((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\right)\ge 0,$$

which is true; or you can use [Rearrangement Inequality](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality).

Equality holds if and only if $x=y=z$, i.e. iff either at least two of $a,b,c$ are equal to $0$ or $abc\neq 0$ and $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

> $$a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2+2a^2bc+2ab^2c+2abc^2\ge3a^2bc+3ab^2c+3abc^2$$
>   $$a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2-a^2bc-ab^2c-abc^2\ge0$$
>   $$2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-2a^2bc-2ab^2c-2abc^2\ge0$$
>   $$(a^2b^2-2a^2bc+a^2c^2)+(a^2c^2-2abc^2+b^2c^2)+(b^2c^2-2ab^2c+a^2b^2)\ge0$$
>   $$(ab-ac)^2+(ac-bc)^2+(ab-bc)^2\ge0$$
>   the upper operation is revertable